# tr td tag, unique id to determine which taable contact I click using v-for and :id

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

My question is simple, I have a `v-for` and unique id assign in `tr` `td` tag table, when I click contenteditable, I want to fire `list_of_products` and recognize from js to know which id field I am changing, the dynamic suppose is `ep_ + i + p.pid`, `ep_` is print text, `i` is index for v-for, and `p.pid` is assign from v-for. Here when I edit td contenteditable and lost focus, it will show an alert which table field I am editing. Here is my tr td table below:

```
<tr class="list_of_productss" v-for="p, i in all_products" :id= "ep_" + i {{p.pid}}>
<td contenteditable data-field="p_code" > {{ p.p_code }} </td>
<td contenteditable data-field="p_fullname"> {{ p.p_fullname }} </td>
<td contenteditable data-field="p_category"> {{ p.p_category }} </td>
<td contenteditable data-field="p_cost"> {{ p.p_cost }} </td>
<td contenteditable data-field="p_margin"> {{ p.p_margin }} </td>
<td contenteditable data-field="p_sell"> {{ p.p_sell }} </td>
</tr>
```

I prefer pure javascript so I do when lost focus in list_of_productss, javascript will know which td I am edit at:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('list_of_productss').addEventListener('blur', function(e) {
  //how to know which id I am typing for i here
  console.log("product_things changed");
  alert("You edit this field with index with data-field" + ) //?? for data-field and i
  });
```

If I do `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementsByClassId`, it must be specific id otherwise I cannot called it , how to make dynamic `getElementsByClassName` or `getElementsByClassId` to make an alert I am edit this specific field, there is total 6 columns for each row. Any help for me is a huge support.

Comment: This should not need any IDs. Subscribe to the `focusout` event instead of `blur` (the former one bubbles up, whereas the latter doesn't) - and then check what the event target was.

Comment: It seems you are asking how to not use Vue when using Vue. But if you decide to use a framework, you really should stick to it and use it properly. You will end up with unmaintainable code otherwise.

Comment: Yes I use Vue, I swith to `id="`ep_${p.pid}`"` and I think it's better now for dynamic id, but not able to called yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**At first**:

Do not use Mustaches `{{}}` in the Vue `attribute bindings` and `v-if/v-show` conditions.

See, [Attribute Bindings](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-syntax.html#attribute-bindings)

> Mustaches cannot be used inside HTML attributes. Instead, use a
> `v-bind` directive

Use string concatenation or [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) `${}`

**Second**:

The tags  seems to not produce `onblur` event. `onfocusout` does work.

Here is the playground with Vue.js and Vanilla Js event handling.

```js
const { createApp, ref, onMounted } = Vue

const App = {
  setup() {
    const all_products = ref([
      { p_code: 1, p_fullname: "One"},
      { p_code: 2, p_fullname: "Two"}
    ]);
    
    onMounted( () => {
      let el = document.getElementsByClassName('list_of_productss');
      for(var i = 0; i< el.length; i++) {
        el[i].addEventListener('focusout', function(e) {
          //how to know which id I am typing for i here
          console.log("product_things changed: " + e.target.id);
        });      
      }
    })
    
    const handleBlur = (e) => {
      console.log("handleBlur: " + e.target.id)
    }
    
    const handleFocusout = (e) => {
      console.log("handleFocusout: " + e.target.id)
    }
    
    return {
      all_products, handleBlur, handleFocusout
    }
  }
}

const app = createApp(App)
app.mount('#app')
```

```css
#app { line-height: 1.75; }
[v-cloak] { display: none; }
td { padding: 30px;}
```

```html
<div id="app" v-cloak>
<table border=1>
  <tr class="list_of_productss" v-for="p, i in all_products" :id= "`ep_${i}`" @blur="handleBlur" @focusout="handleFocusout" >
<td contenteditable data-field="p_code" :id= "`ep_code_${i}`" > {{ p.p_code }} </td>
<td contenteditable data-field="p_fullname" :id= "`ep_fn_${i}`"> {{ p.p_fullname }} </td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3/dist/vue.global.prod.js"></script>
```

Comment: can I a ask quick question, how can I retrieve data-field?

Comment: I got it I use `var sortOrder = e.target.getAttribute("data-field")`, thanks anyway.